# opencv code that works well on pc doesn't work on mac

Tags: python, macos, opencv

I wrote a simple image analysis code function on my lab pc using openCV, and it worked well. For some reason, it won't work on my mac at home. The image pops (for using a trackbar) freezes and does not respond. 
Any ideas why?

Iv'e tried to find the solution to this but couldn't.

```
def leaf2score(file_name):


    #assign strings for ease of coding
    hh='Hue High'
    hl='Hue Low'
    sh='Saturation High'
    sl='Saturation Low'
    vh='Value High'
    vl='Value Low'
    cv2.namedWindow("Tracking") #creating a window named "Tracking"
    cv2.createTrackbar(hl, "Tracking", 0, 179, nothing)
    cv2.createTrackbar(sl, "Tracking", 0, 179, nothing)
    cv2.createTrackbar(vl, "Tracking", 0, 255, nothing)
    cv2.createTrackbar(hh, "Tracking", 255, 255, nothing)
    cv2.createTrackbar(sh, "Tracking", 255, 255, nothing)
    cv2.createTrackbar(vh, "Tracking", 255, 255, nothing)

    #assigning the trackbar values to control the masking of the img
    while True:
        img = cv2.imread(file_name) #reading the image using CV2 
        hsv = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV) #transform the img from BGR to HSV

        frame=cv2.GaussianBlur(hsv,(5,5),0)

        l_h = cv2.getTrackbarPos(hl, "Tracking")
        l_s = cv2.getTrackbarPos(sl, "Tracking")
        l_v = cv2.getTrackbarPos(vl, "Tracking")

        u_h = cv2.getTrackbarPos(hh, "Tracking")
        u_s = cv2.getTrackbarPos(sh, "Tracking")
        u_v = cv2.getTrackbarPos(vh, "Tracking")

        l_green = np.array([l_h, l_s, l_v])  #determining the lower limit for color thresholding (hue, saturation, value)
        u_green = np.array([u_h, u_s, u_v])     #determining the upper limit for color thresholding

        mask = cv2.inRange(frame, l_green, u_green) #creating a mask for our filtration

        res = cv2.bitwise_and(frame, frame, mask=mask) #the RESULT image after applying the mask

        cv2.imshow("frame", frame) #showing each of the images throughout the process
        cv2.imshow("mask", mask)
        cv2.imshow("res", res)

        key = cv2.waitKey(1)  #close image windows
        if key == 27:
            break

    cv2.destroyAllWindows()

    bgr = cv2.cvtColor(res, cv2.COLOR_HSV2BGR) #converting the HSV back to BGR
    b,g,r = cv2.split(bgr) #Splitiing the channels of the image

    mean_g = cv2.mean(g)
    mean_r = cv2.mean(r)
    print(mean_g)
    print(mean_r)
    score = mean_g[0] + mean_r[0]  #calculating the score of the color by summing the green & red channels 


    return (score)
```

Comment: what version of python/opencv are you using? which line causes program to freeze?

Comment: recently updated it to opencv latest version. unfortunately I don't know which line does.

Comment: how did you defined the trackbar callback `nothing`?

Comment: @zteffi In the example (https://docs.opencv.org/trunk/d9/dc8/tutorial_py_trackbar.html) the trackbar callback is also `nothing`.

Comment: @StephenMeschke I would assume from it's name it is defined similarly, however I didn't find other issues with the code.